# -Authorize- not working with 2 ASP.NET MVC controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC web app with 2 controller, 1 that send requests to an API and the other one that will handle **authentication**. The app build just fine but the authorize tag is not working, I can easily access the secret page without having the cookie.

This is the Access controller:

```
public class AccessController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Secret()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And this is the `startup.cs` file:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddControllers();
        // Add session
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession();

        // Add services to the container.
        services.AddSingleton<IClient, ClientConcessionario>();

        services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuth").AddCookie("CookieAuth", config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.Name = "CookieAuth";
            config.LoginPath = "/Access/Login";
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
        ;
    }
}
```

I can views all the urls of both the controllers, but I shouldn't be able to access the secret page without a cookie. Any clue?

Comment: After app.UseRouting(); add app.UseAuthentication();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call UseAuthentication() and UseAuthorization() in Configure method BEFORE UseRouting.